# .attr() doesn't work for the lement created by javascript:appendChild

Tags: jquery, html, append, attr

I have a set of thumbnails like :

```
<div id='thumb' class='anImage.jpeg'>
<img src='anImage.jpg' />
</div>
......
<div id='thumb' class='anotherImage.jpeg'>
<img src='anotherImage.jpg' />
</div>
```

As you can see, I use 'class' of each DIV to be able in future to find needed DIV by Image Name that it contains.

I have an Uploader (ajax imitiated, using iframe). When I upload a new image, my javascript function gets a confirmation from php file. And if it's OK my js code adds ( appendChild at the end ) a new DIV&IMG like below:

```
<div id='thumb' class='newUploaded.jpeg'>
<img src='newUploaded.jpg' />
</div>
```

Now about the problem:
I have another jQuery function that, by clicking on any image (RENAME BUTTON) sends to php file image name that was clicked. But after the file was renamed on server side, I need  to update image name on client side using jQuery. So, i do something like:

```
$.ajax({
.....
success: function(){
   $("div.oldname").attr("class", "newname");
}
.....
});
```

AND it doesn't work only if the file was just created after upload. My code doesn't work for element that was just created by javascript appendChild() function.

Comment: But where do you call `appendChild`?

Comment: I have another part of code for 'file upload using iframe';
In that js function after server side confirmation (file uploaded succesfuly) i need to add new uploaded file to 'thumbnails set', so there I use appendChild() - <div class='newfile'><img src='newfile'/></div>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the old class and adding the new class as opposed to using the .attr() method :

```
$("div.oldname").removeClass('oldname').addClass('newname');
```

Also, is there a reason you are using the file name as a class?

Comment: I just tried. it is the same. works for all elements, but not for new created!
I use DIV classes to keep img name for additional operations. It's easy for me to modify DIV element of certain IMG, so I use imga name (class) to find needed DIV

Answer (score 0):

Found.. problem is

```
<div class="filename"></div>
```

File Name like: img.jpg has a dot :) so we I have incorrect class:

```
$('div.img.jpg').blabla() // more than 1 dot ;
```